# Merge [finagle] and [twitter-finagle]

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonym-process

These tags both refer to the Finagle library by Twitter so I think they should be merged to [finagle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/finagle).

[twitter-finagle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/twitter-finagle)

Comment: I approve this... backwards, merge the tags into [twitter-finagle].

Comment: Yeah... [finagle] sounds like a generic term for doing something tricky and complicated.